# Unable to call Restful Service in AngularJs application

Tags: angularjs, cors

I am trying to create a search application in angularjs.However, i am getting the below error . Can someone please help.

AddrBook.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://121.242.159.36:6006/AddressBookWS/rest/addressBookService/getCompany/%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20JB. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Thanks
Srikala

Answer (score 0):

(1)

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

You are making a cross domain request and this header must be present on the server's response.
The header should be ...
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

To allow any domain to make a request to the server.

This is your problem! If you have control over the server then add the response header. If not then make the request at your backend to circumvent the X-domain policy and then make the data available to your angular app.

...

(2)

Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access -- This is because you are not setting the Origin header in your HTTP request

You can set default headers for all http requests in your app config.

Although (2) will not fix the issue just an FYI.